# KeyError: (0, 1) in Gurobi in Python

Tags: python, keyerror, gurobi

I'm using Gurobi to work to a location problem (p-median problem).
This is a piece of code to solve p-median problem in Gurobi.
Console shows me a `KeyError: (0,1)` for the last line of code.

```py
    def pmedian(m, n, c, p):
           model = gp.Model("p-median")
           y,x = {}, {}
           for j in range(m):
               y[j] = model.addVar(obj=0, vtype="B", name="y[%s]"%j)
               for i in range(n):
                            x[i,j] = model.addVar(obj=c[i,j], vtype="B", name="x[%s,%s]"%(i,j))
                            model.update()
                            coef = [1  for i in range(n) for j in range(m)]
                            var = [x[i,j]  for i in range(n) for j in range(m)]
```

How could I remove the error?

Answer (score -1):

Try to indent better the code. Most of the time that's it.